# Help with derivative of $y=x^2\sin^5x+x\cos^{-5}x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find $y^{\prime}$ of $y=x^2\sin^5x+x\cos^{-5}x$

My try:

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2\sin^5x)=x^2(-5\sin^4x)+(2x\sin^5x)$

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-5}x)=x(-5\cos^{-6}x)+1(\cos^{-5}x)$

This doesn't seem right. Can you please show how to do it correctly?

The answer is $y^{\prime}=x\sin^4(x) ( 2 \sin(x)+5x\cos(x)) +(5x\tan(x)+1)\sec^5x$

Comment: By the chain rule, what is the derivative of $sin^5(x)$? (or the derivative of $cos^{-5}(x)$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$y=x^2\sin^5x+x\cos^{-5}x$$

When taking the derivative of each summand of $y$, you left out a component of the chain rule for each of the trigonometric functions: $$[g(x)]^n = n[g(x)]^{n - 1} \cdot \color{blue}{g'(x)}$$ See the text highlighted in blue:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2\sin^5x)=x^2(5\sin^4x){\bf\color{blue}{ \cos x}}+(2x\sin^5x)$$

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-5}x)=x(-5\cos^{-6}(x){\bf \color{blue}{(-\sin x)}})+1(\cos^{-5}x)$$

$$y' = 5x^2\sin^4x\cos x+ 2x\sin^5x +5x\cos^{-6}x\sin x + \cos^{-5}x$$

Comment: This can be simplified by noting, e.g., that $5x\cos^{-6}x = 5x \sec^6 x$, and factoring out common terms.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU +1

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2\sin^5x)=x^25\sin^4x \cos x+(2x\sin^5x)$

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-5}x)=5x\cos^{-6}x \sin {x}+1(\cos^{-5}x)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{d\color{blue}{f^{\color{red}n}(x)}}{dx}=\color{red}n\color{blue}{f^{\color{red}{n-1}}(x)}\color{grey}{f'(x)}$$